# Magento2 : Can't Override Model File

Tags: magento2, model, bundled-product, override-model

I'm trying to override `Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type` 
for that i have add code in`di.xml`

```
<preference for="Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type" type="Tecksky\Catalog\Model\Product\Type" />
```

And have added file at `app\code\Tecksky\Catalog\Model\Product\Type.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace Tecksky\Catalog\Model\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
use Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection\Collection\FilterApplier as SelectionCollectionFilterApplier;

/**
 * Bundle Type Model
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveClassComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Type extends \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type
{


    /**
     * Catalog data
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_catalogData = null;

    /**
     * Catalog product
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product
     */
    protected $_catalogProduct = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\OptionFactory
     */
    protected $_bundleOption;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection
     */
    protected $_bundleSelection;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config
     */
    protected $_config;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_bundleCollection;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\BundleFactory
     */
    protected $_bundleFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\SelectionFactory $bundleModelSelection
     */
    protected $_bundleModelSelection;

    /**
     * @var PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    protected $priceCurrency;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
     */
    protected $_stockRegistry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface
     */
    protected $_stockState;

    /**
     * @var MetadataPool
     */
    private $metadataPool;

    /**
     * @var SelectionCollectionFilterApplier
     */
    private $selectionCollectionFilterApplier;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $catalogProductOption
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $catalogProductType
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $fileStorageDb
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData
     * @param \Magento\Bundle\Model\SelectionFactory $bundleModelSelection
     * @param \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\BundleFactory $bundleFactory
     * @param \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection\CollectionFactory $bundleCollection
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $config
     * @param \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection $bundleSelection
     * @param \Magento\Bundle\Model\OptionFactory $bundleOption
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer
     * @param MetadataPool|null $metadataPool
     * @param SelectionCollectionFilterApplier|null $selectionCollectionFilterApplier
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $catalogProductOption,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $catalogProductType,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $fileStorageDb,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData,
        \Magento\Bundle\Model\SelectionFactory $bundleModelSelection,
        \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\BundleFactory $bundleFactory,
        \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection\CollectionFactory $bundleCollection,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $config,
        \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection $bundleSelection,
        \Magento\Bundle\Model\OptionFactory $bundleOption,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState,
        Json $serializer = null,
        MetadataPool $metadataPool = null,
        SelectionCollectionFilterApplier $selectionCollectionFilterApplier = null
    ) {
        $this->_catalogProduct = $catalogProduct;
        $this->_catalogData = $catalogData;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_bundleOption = $bundleOption;
        $this->_bundleSelection = $bundleSelection;
        $this->_config = $config;
        $this->_bundleCollection = $bundleCollection;
        $this->_bundleFactory = $bundleFactory;
        $this->_bundleModelSelection = $bundleModelSelection;
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
        $this->_stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        $this->_stockState = $stockState;

        $this->metadataPool = $metadataPool
            ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(MetadataPool::class);

        $this->selectionCollectionFilterApplier = $selectionCollectionFilterApplier
            ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SelectionCollectionFilterApplier::class);

        parent::__construct(
            $catalogProductOption,
            $eavConfig,
            $catalogProductType,
            $eventManager,
            $fileStorageDb,
            $filesystem,
            $coreRegistry,
            $logger,
            $productRepository,
            $serializer
        );
    }

  /**
     * Retrieve bundle selections collection based on used options
     *
     * @param array $optionIds
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection\Collection
     */
    public function getSelectionsCollection($optionIds, $product)
    {
        $storeId = $product->getStoreId();

        $metadata = $this->metadataPool->getMetadata(
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class
        );

        $selectionsCollection = $this->_bundleCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_config->getProductAttributes())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('tax_class_id') //used for calculation item taxes in Bundle with Dynamic Price
            ->addAttributeToSelect('weight')
            ->setFlag('product_children', true)
            ->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreFilter($product))
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
            ->setOptionIdsFilter($optionIds);

        $this->selectionCollectionFilterApplier->apply(
            $selectionsCollection,
            'parent_product_id',
            $product->getData($metadata->getLinkField())
        );

        if (!$this->_catalogData->isPriceGlobal() && $storeId) {
            $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)
                ->getWebsiteId();
            $selectionsCollection->joinPrices($websiteId);
        }

        return $selectionsCollection;
    }
}
```

I have just added  `->addAttributeToSelect('weight')` to this function.
How to override this function?

Answer (score 2):

drop your `__construct` method because you are not adding anything new to it compared to the original class. Also you may need to copy all of the private methods from the original class into yours.

But to solve your problem....  you don't need to add `weight` to the select. Just edit the attribute in the backend and set the flag "Used in product listing" to "Yes". It should be picked up automatically.
A reindexing may be needed.

Comment: thanks it's solved. but I have copied all private method but still not override class? how is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add **weight** attribute to collection, then you just

enable this attribute "**Used in Product Listing**" from

***admin > Stores > Attributes > Product*** .Select `weight` attribute and then goto Storefront Properties.